# Delete extension border

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

How can I delete the top and bottom corner from chrome extension?
[image]

Comment: You can't. But you can add left and right border on `<body>` element to make it uniform.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've thought about that, but I saw other extensions that didn't have those borders.

Comment: You didn't. There are no such extensions. The only other method is to have a white background so it blends with the top and bottom borders.

Comment: @XenzLSD, what you've seen - it not a popup. It is a div-element injected to a webpage via content-script. It has top right position.